# Cannot connect to http://localhost:50030/ - Hadoop 2.6.0 Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hadoop2

I have Hadoop 2.6.0 installed on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine. I am able to successfully connect to `http://localhost:50070/`.

I am trying to connect to `http://locahost:50030/` I have the following in my `mapred-site.xml`

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
        <value>localhost:9001</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Yet I continue to get an error of not being able to connect. I ran the jps command and got the following output:

```
12272 Jps
10059 SecondaryNameNode
6675 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
10233 ResourceManager
9867 DataNode
9745 NameNode
10362 NodeManager
```

So my name and data nodes are both running.

If I need to post anymore information please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using hadoop 2.6.0, job tracker is replaced by YARN. The port number to look for is 8088.
Try http://localhost:8088

Comment: why when using `start-dfs.sh` and `start-yarn.sh` does `http://localhost:50070/` now not work? I am going to mark this answer as accepted but would like to know why `http://localhost:8088` is now the only one that works?

Comment: In hadoop 2 JobTracker was replaced by ResourceManagaer. http://localhost:50070/ is the url to check job tracker, it does not work because there is no JobTracker.

Answer (score 0):

http://localhost:50070/ node manager is not working because you run command prompt without Administrator rights. Run command prompt with "Run As Administrator" option, then it will work.