# How to access hadoop web UI in linux?

Tags: linux, hadoop

I have installed Hadoop 2.7.3 as per the following tutorial [Digital ocean tutorial for installing hadoop in stand-alone mode](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-hadoop-in-stand-alone-mode-on-ubuntu-16-04). After installing i have started **start-dfs.sh** but when I started I got the following output.

```
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
jtech@localhost's password: 
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-jtech-namenode-jtech.out
jtech@localhost's password: 
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-jtech-datanode-jtech.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
jtech@0.0.0.0's password: 
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-jtech-secondarynamenode-jtech.out
```

But when I try to access urls from my web browser, for example, `localhost:50030` or `0.0.0.0:50030` I get **Unable to connect** error in Firefox.

Update: Neither, did localhost:8088 did work as from the answer in the question stated in the comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot connect to http://localhost:50030/ - Hadoop 2.6.0 Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31232915/cannot-connect-to-http-localhost50030-hadoop-2-6-0-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Comment: You could just use Cloudera or Hortonworks VMs if you only want to learn about hadoop.

Comment: @cricket_007 No, the answer of that question (connecting to localhost:8088) did not work. I got same error.

Comment: Okay. My bad. You can run `netstat -anl` to see all listening ports

Comment: Besides, you only started the namenode, not YARN, so right, 8088 shouldn't work

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, Now i started yarn, and 8088 did work but not others

Comment: Did you also run `start-mapred.sh`?

Comment: @cricket_007 https://gist.github.com/1ca86df4760fcf8c7ec1dd08858e900c These are the ports that are actually active in my pc

Comment: @cricket_007 Where is start-mapred.sh?

Comment: Should be in the same location as the start dfs, as far as I know. Maybe my information is outdated... Anyway  `50075` is a datanode http port. Personally, I don't really use the Hadoop UI. `hadoop fs -ls /` is all you need to browse HDFS

Comment: The output of the command you said is ls: Call From `jtech/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused`

Comment: @cricket_007 https://gist.github.com/37f0f16dae1c5b7f5071c7076bb78a2e These are the only files in `sbin` dir of hadoop

Comment: Okay, then stop-all and start-all are the ones you can try. Regarding that error, you can read that URL provided

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131171/discussion-between-javatechnical-and-cricket-007).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following along the [official Single-Node setup documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html)

> 1. Format the filesystem:
>
>    ```
>    $ bin/hdfs namenode -format
>    ```
> 2. Start NameNode daemon and DataNode daemon:
>
>    ```
>    $ sbin/start-dfs.sh
>    ```
> 3. Browse the web interface for the NameNode; by default it is available at:
>
>    NameNode - http://localhost:50070/

If you don't format the namenode, it won't start

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've also posted that answer (Redundant). Any way, it may contain some other useful information, (mistakes) that I have done.

Comment: Welcome. Yeah, the note about `ssh` is also in the official docs, which is why I claim that DigitialOcean post skips over the "base setup".

Comment: When today I started, again. But it didn't come. I need to format it again and then it came. Do I need to format it every time? Is there any alternative?

Comment: If you shut-off the machine without running `stop-dfs.sh` or `stop-all.sh`, then you corrupted some files probably.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the HDFS needs to be formatted using. Before this, I need to run `/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/stop-all.sh`

```
bin/hdfs namenode -format
bin/hdfs secondarynamenode -format -checkpoint force
bin/hdfs datanode -format
```

and then start it again.

```
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-all.sh
```

Then it works.

---

Note: For jps to work, you need to install `openjdk-8-jdk-headless` or something suitable to your Java version.
Your Java version can be known by.

```
readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::"
```

If it is 8, then install `openjdk-8-jdk-headless`.

You'll also need `ssh`. Though you get the commands `ssh` when you type in terminal, still you need `sudo apt-get install ssh`

More at: [Configuring Hadoop in Ubuntu for Standalone mode (generally, for students)](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html). Follow, all steps though you think that the you have all the software. The software may need to update its alternatives.

In the above url, don't also forget to change the configuration files given under **Pseudo-Distributed Operation** section.

First, you may need to take a look at [Installing Hadoop in Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-hadoop-in-stand-alone-mode-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 2):

Try going to the port 50070, http://localhost:50070. If that works HDFS is up and running. Since you are using > 2.2.0 there is no JobTracker. See `jps` and you should see

```
$jps
Jps
NameNode
DataNode
ResourceManager
NodeManager
JobHistoryServer
```

See if you can get to the resource manager http port http://localhost:8088.

Comment: @JavaTechnical Make sure the services are started (I listed them in my edit)

Comment: The program 'jps' can be found in the following packages:
 * openjdk-8-jdk-headless
 * openjdk-9-jdk-headless

Comment: @JavaTechnical Get jps working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738070/hadoop-cannot-use-jps-command. Make sure your JAVA_HOME is set correct as well. You can also check hadoop logs (typically in /var/log/hadoop...(name of service)

Comment: `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/` I have done it as in the above said url (in question) in hadoop-env.sh

Comment: jps worked for me. But NameNode, ResourceManager, JobHistoryServer didn't start.

Comment: @JavaTechnical need to determine why those services didn't come up. Any logs to show why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131181/discussion-between-javatechnical-and-kevin-vasko).

Comment: Thanks for the jps tip! It shows what services are started