# accessing hadoop job tracker ui

Tags: python, hadoop

I'm trying to setup a `hadoop cluster`. Currently, I have setup a master node and submitted a map reduce job using Python.
The jobs got submitted and I can see the results in the console.

Now, I had been trying to view the job tracker web ui to see the job properties but not sure which port should I use?

`ipaddress : 50070` - Shows me all the namenode and datanode

`ipaddress : 8088` - Shows me the cluster information

Which port should I use to view the job tracker? I tried `port 50030` but nothing is displayed.

Using hadoop version 2.7.3

Comment: `8088` is YARN, and that is what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31232915/cannot-connect-to-http-localhost50030-hadoop-2-6-0-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: You should be able to see all the applications in `8088`!

Comment: I am able to access 8088 but I dont see the job that was submitted in the console.

Comment: Are you running `jobhistoryserver`? If yes, the UI will be available by default in port `19888`. Can you check for finished applications there?

Comment: Or, was the job submitted locally? What is the value set for property `mapreduce.framework.name` in `mapred-site.xml`? If nothing is set, it will be running the job locally and will not be displayed in YARN UI.

Comment: I dont see any value set for mapreduce.framework.name , what should be the correct value to be set, so that it can be displayed on the YARN?

Comment: set the value as `yarn` in the file `mapred-site.xml`. The file will not be there, create one from the template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I dont see any value set for mapreduce.framework.name , what should be the correct value to be set, so that it can be displayed on the YARN?

You don't see it, so it is the default

> Property `mapreduce.framework.name`
>   Default: `local`
>   Description: The runtime framework for executing MapReduce jobs. Can be one of `local`, `classic` or `yarn`.

[`mapred-default.xml`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml)

---

You need to update `mapred-site.xml` with that property set to `yarn`